# Python selenium new line

Tags: python, selenium

How can i perform new line?
This is the output: 
**Lname, Fname MICourse: IT**

How can i make it like this?
**Lname, Fname MI**
**Course: IT**

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import keyboard
import time

```
    keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
    keyboard.write('int main()')
    time.sleep(2)

keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
keyboard.write('{')
time.sleep(2)

keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
keyboard.write('printf("Name: Lname, Fname MI"); ')
time.sleep(1)

keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
keyboard.write('\nprintf("Course: IT"); ')
time.sleep(2)

keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')

keyboard.write('return 0; ')
time.sleep(2)

keyboard.press_and_release('F9')
time.sleep(5)
cautomate.close()
```

Comment: what is keyboard ? is i a library ?. Please add imports

Answer (score 0):

printf doesn't print with a newline by default, so change it to

```
keyboard.write('printf("Name: Lname, Fname MI\n"); ')
```